# extract parameters from string

Tags: php, regex

I have problem, that i have no idea where to start from even.

I have pattern list like this:

```
$pattern[1]="something%var1%aaa";
$pattern[2]="something else %MyVar% with more %variable%s";
$givenString="something else 12 with more 1234s";
```

and i want to know pattern index, thay my string matches (if any) and, if so, list of values and variable names in that pattern, for example, in this case, i will get:

```
$patternId=2;
$variables['MyVar']=12;
$variables['variable']=1234;
```

or, if no pattern matches, i will also know it.

It does not have to be % closed, it can be {...} or $...$ or anything else like that.

I've spend some time on it, but all i found was some regular expressions quite similar to what i need, but not exactly. The main problem was, that i need my parameters to be named, and regular expressions have only (\s+), (\d+) etc. and i have to name all those params, because this will allow me to not have to write all those IFs when i have 500 patterns with multiple configurations of 5 variables.

Comment: Please Show all possibilities of pattern

Comment: And what have you tried? Please share your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). see http://docs.php.net/pcre

e.g.

```
<?php
$givenString="something else 12 with more 1234s";
$patterns = [
    "!something%var1%aaa!",
    "!something else (\d+) with more (\d+)s!"
];

foreach($patterns as $idx=>$p) {
    if ( preg_match($p, $givenString, $matches) ) {
        echo $idx, ' match: [', join('] [', $matches), "]\r\n";
    }
}
```

prints

```
1 match: [something else 12 with more 1234s] [12] [1234]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use preg_match? This should be simple, for example:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/^something else (\d+) with more (\d+)s$/", $givenString, $matches);
```

After this runs $matches[1] will contain the first match enclosed in () which is MyVar, $matches[2] will contain the second match in () which is variable, etc.

Comment: Thank you, i've tried with expressions, but i have no idea how to make reg exp with named parameters.

Comment: @MateuszKuśnierz: for named groups: use `(?P<name_of_group>\d+)` instead of `(\d+)`.